# How to extract video url for desktop playback

Tags: embedly

Embedly normally returns a web player like in this example with Vimeo:
http://embed.ly/code?url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F192417650

Is there a way to extract a URL I could use for desktop playback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Embedly load the iframe of the video provider.

If you want to extract just data, I recommend you use https://microlink.io:

http://api.microlink.io/?url=https://vimeo.com/192417650

Check the documentation to check what kind of information you can get.